# Задать элементам массива значения в виде случайного текста заданной длины

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как задать элементам массива значения содержащие случайный текст заданной длины.

```
$arr = array(
      'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
      'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
      'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
      's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
      'y', 'z'
    );
    function get_array($count,$lenght,$arr) //$lenght - длина текста, $count - кол-во элементов массива
    {
        $word = "";
        for ($i=0; $i < $lenght; $i++) 
        {
        $word .= $arr[mt_rand(0, count($arr) - 1)];
        $word_arr = array_fill(1, $count, $word);
        }
        return $word_arr;
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(get_array(5,13,$arr));
```

Значения должно быть уникальным для каждого элемента, а не как у меня пока выходит:

```
Array
    (
        [1] => afmervwyahjst
        [2] => afmervwyahjst
        [3] => afmervwyahjst
        [4] => afmervwyahjst
        [5] => afmervwyahjst
    )
```

Comment: если Вы получили ответ на Ваш вопрос, то отметьте наиболее подходящий ответ "галочкой" слева от ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ещё вариант

```
// $count —  кол-во элементов массива
// $lenght —  длина текста
function get_array($count, $lenght, $arr) 
{   
    // выходной массив
    $word_arr = array();

    // цикл — колво элементов массива ($count)
    for ($c = 0; $c < $count; $c++)
    {
        // формируем слово из входящего массив
        $word = '';

        // цикл по колву длины слова
        for ($k = 0; $k < $lenght; $k++) 
        {
            // перемешиваем массив, чтобы получить случайное значение
            shuffle($arr);

            // заполняем слово
            $word .= $arr[0];
        }

        // слово в выходной массив
        $word_arr[] = $word;
    }

    return $word_arr;
}

$arr = array(
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
    'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
    'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
    's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
    'y', 'z'
);

echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_array(5, 13, $arr));
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы заполняете массив одним и тем же значением через array_fill.
Вот тут можно посмотреть пример: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php

Чтобы все работало как надо - попробуйте вот это.

```
<?php

function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}


    function get_array($count,$lenght,$arr) //$lenght - длина текста, $count - кол-во элементов массива
    {
        $word_arr = array();
        for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
        {
            array_push($word_arr, generateRandomString($lenght));
        }
        return $word_arr;
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(get_array(5,13,$arr));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если длина генерируемой строки меньше самого алфавита, то вариант решения с использованием [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shuffle.php) может быть таков:

```
function getArray($count, $len, $chars){
    $result = [];
    while($count--){
        shuffle($chars);
        $result[] = implode('',array_slice($chars, 0, $len));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

В целом, конечно,  уникальность тут не гарантируется.

вместо того, чтобы отрезать первые `$len` элементов из массива, можно также взять `$len` случайных ключей с помощью `array_rand()`. В т.ч. можно вообще не использовать `shuffle` а просто брать случайные ключи, то есть как-то так:

```
while($count--){
    $result[] = implode('', array_intersect_key($chars, array_flip( array_rand($chars, $len))));
}
```

но `array_rand` (по крайней мере в старых версиях пхп), дает не очень хорошее распределение.